# Less-loader module is not getting detected

Tags: webpack-dev-server

List item

I am trying to implement less-loader in my web pack, for that 
 I've installed less-loader successfully to my env which is also getting reflected in `package.json` and `node_modules`. But still when I'm building `webpack` it's not getting 'less' module.

```
module: {
      rules: [{
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
            // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
            transpileOnly: true
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.less$/,
          use: [{
              loader: 'style-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: 'less-loader',
            }
          ]
        }
```

> Warning: less-loader@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "l ess@^2.3.1 ||
>   ^3.0.0".
>
> ERROR in ./src/app/features/common/common.less
>   (/gudena/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!/gudena/node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/app/features/common/common.less)
>   app_1_9a4398ee6236         | [CLIENT] Module build failed (from
>   /gudena/node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js): app_1_9a4398ee6236
>   | [CLIENT] Error: Cannot find module 'less'

Please let me know what is restricting 'less' loader to be detected.